# Call JavaScript function from workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, javascript

I want to call a JavaScript function from a workflow. I want to create a SharePoint Designer workflow with a pause. How do I call JavaScript functions from a workflow?

Comment: which workflow you are using? Designer workflow/ custom workflow using VS/ Third party workflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a JavaScript function is not supported by any kind of workflow manager which means that you cannot call your java scripts functions in workflow. Now if  you want to perform something in list, you have an option of using Web Service. So you can research more on web service instead of calling java script

Answer (score 0):

You can not call JavaScript function but you can call web service from SharePoint workflow.

[Working with Web Services in SharePoint 2013 Workflows using SharePoint Designer 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx)

Comment: Dipongor is correct. Workflows are running server side. On a .net environment Javascript functions can only be run on the client side.
So, no, it is not possible to call a javascript from a workflow.